# Why does my function always return the same values?

Tags: r, function, loops, colors

I have a function "xy_from_Temperature" which is supposed to compute XYZ color coordinates from a spectral power distribution. However, no matter what temperature I put into it, it always ouputs

```
[1] 0.2398770 0.2340373
```

My code is

```r
xy_from_Temperature <- function (Temperature){
  X_vector <- c()
  Y_vector <- c()
  Z_vector <- c()
  repetition_counter <- 1
  wavelength_counter <- 360
  for (i in 360:830){
    X <- Color_Matching_Function[,2][repetition_counter]
    Y <- Color_Matching_Function[,3][repetition_counter]
    Z <- Color_Matching_Function[,4][repetition_counter]
    Spectral_Radiance <- Spectral_Radiant_Exitance (wavelength_counter, Temperature)
    X <- X * Spectral_Radiance
    Y <- Y * Spectral_Radiance
    Z <- Z * Spectral_Radiance
    X_vector <- c(X_vector, X)
    Y_vector <- c(Y_vector, Y)
    Z_vector <- c(Z_vector, Z)
    repetition_counter <- repetition_counter + 1
    wavelength_counter <- wavelength_counter + 1
  }
  sum_X <- sum(X_vector)
  sum_Y <- sum(Y_vector)
  sum_Z <- sum(Z_vector)
  XYZ <- c(sum_X, sum_Y, sum_Z)
  xy <- XYZ_to_xy(XYZ)
  return (xy)
}
```

Spectral_Radiant_Exitance is a function that takes wavelength (in nanometers) and temperature (in kelvin) and ouputs spectral radiant exitance (as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus#The_Planckian_locus_in_the_XYZ_color_space)). XYZ_to_xy is a function that takes a vector of XYZ color coordinates and outputs a vector of xy color coordinates (also as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus#The_Planckian_locus_in_the_XYZ_color_space)).

Color_Matching_Function is a dataframe of the CIE 1931 2 degree color matching function for xyz color space which I copy-pasted from the file [on this page](https://cie.co.at/datatable/cie-1931-colour-matching-functions-2-degree-observer).

I based "xy_from_Temperature" on the equations I found in [this webpage](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_Spect_to_XYZ.html).

I have tried inputting various temperature such as 10, 2000, and 40000, but it always outputs the same result. It should output results on the [Planckian locus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwCwR.png).

So if I input 4000, I should get

```
[1] 0.38 0.38
```

(approximately), and if I input 10000, I should get

```
[1] 0.53 0.42
```

(also approximately). I have truly no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Spectral_Radiant_Exitance is defined as

```r
    Spectral_Radiant_Exitance <- function (wavelength, temperature){
  M <- 1 / (wavelength^5 * ((exp(c2 / (wavelength * temperature))) - 1))
  return (M)
}
```

where c2 is 0.01438786.

Edit 2:
XYZ_to_xy is defined as

```r
XYZ_to_xy <- function (XYZ_vector){
  X <- XYZ_vector[1]
  Y <- XYZ_vector[2]
  Z <- XYZ_vector[3]
  x <- X / (X + Y + Z)
  y <- Y / (X + Y + Z)
  xy_vector <- c(x,y)
  return (xy_vector)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in `xy_from_Temperature` and not in `Spectral_Radiant_Exitance`? Since that is the only place you are using `Temperature`, that should be the first place you look for bugs.

Comment: A side note, "growing" vectors by making them 1 item longer each time you go through a loop is a notorious performance killer. Your function would be **much** more efficient if you defined `X_vector <- Y_vector <- Z_vector <- numeric(length(360:830))` so they are all the full length **before** the loop and inside the loop assigned values to the correct positions, `X_vector[repetition_counter] <- X`, etc.

Comment: @GregorThomas I am fairly certain that Spectral_Radiant_Exitance isn't the problem. I checked results I got with it against results with Wolfram Alpha and they were identical (except Wolfram Alpha was more precise). It also changes if I change the wavelength or temperature by 1. I added it to the bottom of my post if anyone wants to take a look at it though. Also, thank you very much for your suggestion on efficiency! I added it to my code and it runs a great deal faster now!

Comment: "where c2 is 0.01438786" That should either be assigned within the function, or c2 be made a function argument, in which the value is passed through when the function is called.

Comment: Could you provide your definition of `XYZ_to_xy()`?

Comment: @Phil Just did it! Thank you very much for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue, and can pinpoint to where the problem is (`XYZ_to_xy()`). But I can't offer a solution to fix it because I have zero domain knowledge about this.

Your code, broadly speaking, doesn't leverage R's ability to vectorize. You don't need to do a for loop at all, you can just vectorize across the `Color_Matching_Function` data frame. The following code condenses your code in much more compact, readable form:

```
library(dplyr)

Color_Matching_Function <- readr::read_csv("CIE_xyz_1931_2deg.csv", col_names = FALSE) |> 
  rename(wavelength = X1, x_bar = X2, y_bar = X3, z_bar = X4)

Spectral_Radiant_Exitance <- function(wavelength, temperature){
  1 / (wavelength^5 * ((exp(0.01438786 / (wavelength * temperature))) - 1))
}

XYZ_to_xy <- function(x, y, z) {
  x_t <- x / (x + y + z)
  y_t <- y / (x + y + z)
  list(x_t, y_t)
}

calculate_radiance <- function(Temperature, Color_Matching = Color_Matching_Function) {
  Color_Matching |> 
    mutate(Spectral_Radiance = Spectral_Radiant_Exitance(wavelength, Temperature),
           across(x_bar:z_bar, ~ .x * Spectral_Radiance, .names = "{col}_Radiance")) |>
    summarize(across(x_bar_Radiance:z_bar_Radiance, sum))
}

res <- calculate_radiance(4000)
res

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  x_bar_Radiance y_bar_Radiance z_bar_Radiance
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1       0.000328       0.000320       0.000718

res2 <- calculate_radiance(10000)
res2

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  x_bar_Radiance y_bar_Radiance z_bar_Radiance
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1       0.000819       0.000799        0.00180
```

I can't say if these values are correct or not, but they're certainly different.

However, the following gets the same results you mention, regardless of the value applied to `Temperature`.

```
XYZ_to_xy(res$x_bar_Radiance, res$y_bar_Radiance, res$z_bar_Radiance)
XYZ_to_xy(res2$x_bar_Radiance, res2$y_bar_Radiance, res2$z_bar_Radiance)
```

Both return

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.239877

[[2]]
[1] 0.2340373
```

Which points to my misunderstanding on how to define `XYZ_to_xy()`, and I am assuming yours as well. I can't help you further I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems in your code, and they both have to do with the **calculation of the radiant exitance by** `Spectral_Radiant_Exitance()`. In order of importance the errors are:

1. The `wavelength` value should be in `nm` (**nanometers**), as deduced from the second graph in the Wikipedia page on the Planckian locus, and as mentioned in the source for the `Color_Matching_Function` data frame, namely: "*Description:
   CIE 1931 colour-matching functions (x_bar, y_bar, z_bar), 2 degree observer, 1 nm wavelength steps*". **You are defining the values for `wavelength` in their nanometer scale but they are interpreted in meters** (i.e. 360 should be replaced with 360E-9 and so forth).
2. Constant `c1` is set to 1 instead of `c1 = 2*pi*h*c^2 = 3.741772e-16`.

When the `wavelength` value is in meters, the exponential of the formula for the radiant exitance is always near 1, regardless of temperature because its exponent `c2/(wavelength * temperature)` is almost 0 (as `wavelength` is 10^9 larger than it should be!).

### Incorrect calculation of the radiant exitance

Here is the graph of the exponential in the denominator of `M(wavelength, temperature)` ("Spectral exponential") and of `M(wavelength, temperature)` itself computed for temperatures 1500, 4000, 10000, **when the `wavelength` values are defined INCORRECTLY** as `360 m, 361 m, etc.`. The vertical scale is logarithmic for better visualization. We can see that the vertical scale of `S_values` are all equal to 1 in essence, and that the `M(wavelength, temperature)` curves are essentially parallel in the log scale (which probably is responsible for making the ratios computed to get the projected values of `x` and `y` always take the same values, regardless of temperature).

[image: Spectral exponential]
[image: Radiant exitance]

### CORRECT calculation of the radiant exitance

And here is the graph of those quantities, also computed for temperatures 1500, 4000, 10000, **when the `wavelength` values are defined CORRECTLY** as `360 nm, 361 nm, etc.`. The vertical scale is still logarithmic. We can now see that the `S_values` are clearly distinct, and that the `M(wavelength, temperature)` curves are no longer parallel in log scale.

[image: Spectral exponential]
[image: Radiant exitance]

Finally, this is the code I used to get the correct graphs (note in particular the use of the multiplier `1E-9` when defining the variable `wavelength`):

```
# Constants definition
h = 6.62607015E-34  # Planck's constant [J s]
c = 299792458       # Speed of light [m/s]
k = 1.380649E-23    # Boltzmann constant [J/K]
c1 = 2*pi*h*c^2
c2 = h*c/k

# Check units of c1 and c2 
# c1 / wavelength^5 = [Js m^2/s^2] / [m^5] = [J/(m^3s)] --> OK! (Power/(sq.m * m))
# c2 / (lambda T) = [Js m/s K/J] / [m K] = [1]  --> OK! (unitless)

# Functions definition
Spectral_Exponential = function(wavelength, temperature) {
  return(exp(c2 / (wavelength * temperature)))
}

Spectral_Radiant_Exitance <- function (wavelength, temperature){
  M <- c1 / (wavelength^5 * (exp(c2 / (wavelength * temperature)) - 1))
  return(M)
}
   
# Generate the graphs for the spectral exponential and for the radiant exitance
wavelength = seq(360, 830, 50)*1E-9
temperatures = c(1500, 4000, 10000)
S_values <- M_values <- matrix(nrow=length(wavelength), ncol=length(temperatures))
j = 0
for (temp in temperatures) {
  j = j + 1
  S_values[, j] = Spectral_Exponential(wavelength, temp)
  M_values[, j] = Spectral_Radiant_Exitance(wavelength, temp)
}

matplot(wavelength, S_values, type="o", pch=21, bg="black", main="Spectral exponential (lambda, T)", log="y")
matplot(wavelength, M_values, type="o", pch=21, bg="black", main="M(lambda, T)", log="y")
```